# Populating RecyclerView with all of the childs of Realtime Database with certain value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have to populate a RecyclerView with all of the children that have `favourite = true`, this is my database structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C6Ys.png

**EDIT**
The response I was looking is in the comments provided by alex

```
val queryByFav = db.child("Users").child("mikeyreid2002gmailcom").orderByChild("favourite").equalTo(true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to return all children which have the `favourite` = true, the following query is required:

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val queryByFav = db.child("Users").orderByChild("testing provider a/favourite").equalTo(true);
```

This query will work **only** if all the other users have the exact same structure:

```
testing provider a/favourite
```

If they don't, then make sure to have a fixed child and not a dynamic one.

Comment: testing provider a is the name made up by three variables. If let's say those variables are a b & c could I use .orderByChild("$a $b $c/favourite").equalTo(true)

Comment: I'm also not sure of the difference between fixed childs and dynamic ones, is there a link for some documentation I could use? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: No, you cannot use it that way. FIxed means that each object should contain the exact node. For example, each node should contain exactly this `testing provider a` and **not** `testing provider b`.

Comment: Hey Miguel. Can I help with other information?

Comment: So is there a way I can get all of the childs of mikeyreid2002gmailcom with favourite to true without knowing the name of such child? I am trying to update a recyclerView which is filled with all of the childs of mikeyreid... to only the favourites when I filter it and it's the only way I can think of doing it

Comment: If you only want to get the children of `mikeyreid2002gmailcom`, then you should use `val queryByFav = db.child("Users").child("mikeyreid2002gmailcom").orderByChild("favourite").equalTo(true);`. But it will return Provied objects and not User objects. Is that what you need?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed thank you so much I'm sorry if I wasn't very clear english isn't my first language.